# Is Gin support rewrite HTTP requests and forward them to the specific API groups?

Tags: go, httpserver, go-gin

My team is going to refactor our gin http server to support routing by domain. For example, the old url for login is `https://www.example.com/login`, and the new url will be `https://login.example.com/`. I was going to rewrite http requests and forward them to the old `/login` group so that all the validations and middlewares, which are very complicate and messy, could be apply to the new style.

Seems like there is no examples in the [document](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin).

Comment: are you looking for a reverse proxy?

Comment: @blackgreen hi, thanks for the tip, but i don't really want to add an nginx for reverse proxying. The situation is much more complicate than what i said, I will have to do some dirty works like DB accessing to rewrite the requests .

Comment: sorry, that's not what I mean. I mean using the Gin server as a reverse proxy, which is, seemingly, what you are asking

Comment: @blackgreen sorry for the misunderstanding. it's like some kind of reverse proxying in memory i guess, i want to rewrite http requests and send them to one specific API group instead of another http server.

Comment: my best guess is i can add a filter to rewrite the new url style to the old style, but i can not find the document or examples for adding a filter.

Comment: if you want to rewrite the url, I think you are better off with something in front of the gin server, i.e. nginx. Another option is to handle the request in Gin as you did before and use the same handler for both old and new routes. Rewriting the url in Gin instead is, IMO, a poorer solution.

Comment: @blackgreen yes, but an extra nginx is not quite the solution i would prefer. Like i said, the rewrite function is very complicate.

Comment: @blackgreen the 'Another option' is a workable idea, maybe i will have to handle it on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd second the suggestion to use a reverse proxy (e.g. nginx, Caddy, etc) in front of your services to do the routing.

I can also understand if you would like to have a little bit more control over  the routing, you can use middlewares. The gin engine supports the use of middleware functions via `routerInstance.Use(middlewareFunc)`.

A middleware is simply a function that returns `gin.HandlerFunc`. I found this  set of examples on the Web: https://sosedoff.com/2014/12/21/gin-middleware.html

Comment: it's exactly the answer i want. nginx's ngx_http_rewrite_module is cool as long as the rewrite rules can be easily described with regular expressions.

Comment: @AndyChow happy to help. Please, consider accepting the answer, so that others can find it mor easily. Thanks!